# UseEffect does not recognize imported components and is not called first

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, kibana, elk

I'm wiriting a kibana plugin and I have some problems with a flyout component. That's my starting code:

```
export const InputPipelineDebugger = ({queryParams, setQueryParams, setConnectionType, setMessage}) => {

const onChangeTest = (e) => {
   setMessage(e.target.value);
}

const onTabConnectionTypeClicked = (tab) => {
    setConnectionType(tab.id);
}



var tabsConnection = [
    {
        id: 'http',
        name: 'HTTP',
        content: <HttpInput onChangeTest = {onChangeTest} queryParams = {queryParams} setQueryParams={setQueryParams} />
    },
    {
        id: 'syslog',
        name: 'SYSLOG',
        content: <SyslogInput onChangeTest = {onChangeTest}  />
    },
    {
        id: 'beats',
        name: 'BEAT',
        content: <BeatsInput onChangeTest = {onChangeTest} />
    }
];

return (
    <EuiFlexItem>
        <h3>Input</h3>
        <EuiTabbedContent
            tabs={tabsConnection}
            initialSelectedTab={tabsConnection[0]}
            autoFocus="selected"
            onTabClick={tab => {
                onTabConnectionTypeClicked(tab);
            }} />
    </EuiFlexItem>
);
```

}

And what I want is to dynamically build the tabs array according to the response from a rest call. So I was trying to use the useEffect method and for that I change the tabsConnection with a state (and a default value, that works WITHOUT the useEffect method) but is not working at all. Console saids to me that the 'content' value from the tabs array is undefined, like if it's not recognizing the imports.

How can I achieve my goal? Thanks for the support

```
export const InputPipelineDebugger = ({queryParams, setQueryParams, setConnectionType, setMessage}) => {

//initialized with a default value
const [tabs, setTabs] = useState([{
    id: 'syslog',
    name: 'SYSLOG',
    content: <SyslogInput onChangeTest = {onChangeTest}  />
}]);

const onChangeTest = (e) => {
   setMessage(e.target.value);
}

const onTabConnectionTypeClicked = (tab) => {
    setConnectionType(tab.id);
}

useEffect(()=>{
    //rest call here;

    //some logics

    var x = [{
        id: 'beats',
        name: 'BEATS',
        content: <BeatsInput onChangeTest = {onChangeTest} />
    }];

    setTabs(x);
}, []);

return (
    <EuiFlexItem>
        <h3>Input</h3>
        <EuiTabbedContent
            tabs={tabs}
            initialSelectedTab={tabs[0]}
            autoFocus="selected"
            onTabClick={tab => {
                onTabConnectionTypeClicked(tab);
            }} />
    </EuiFlexItem>
);
```

}

Errors from the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined
at EuiTabbedContent.render
```

EDIT 1

Here the code of BeatsInput and SyslogInput:

```
    import {
    EuiText,
    EuiTextArea,
    EuiSpacer,
    EuiFlexItem,
} from '@elastic/eui';

import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';

export const SyslogInput = ({onChangeTest}) => {
    return (
        <EuiFlexItem>
            <EuiFlexItem >
                <EuiSpacer />
                <EuiText >
                    <EuiTextArea fullWidth={true}
                        style={{ height: "450px" }}
                        onChange={e => onChangeTest(e)}
                        placeholder="Scrivi l'input"
                    />
                </EuiText>
            </EuiFlexItem>
        </EuiFlexItem>
    )
}

import {
    EuiText,
    EuiTextArea,
    EuiSpacer,
    EuiFlexItem,
} from '@elastic/eui';

import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';

export const BeatsInput = ({onChangeTest}) => {
    return (
        <EuiFlexItem>
            <EuiFlexItem >
                <EuiSpacer />
                <EuiText >
                    <EuiTextArea fullWidth={true}
                        style={{ height: "450px" }}
                        onChange={e => onChangeTest(e)}
                        placeholder="Scrivi l'input"
                    />
                </EuiText>
            </EuiFlexItem>
        </EuiFlexItem>
    )
}
```

Comment: the only warning when I replicated this was onChangeTest being passed in useState before its declaration; can you verify useEffect and BeatsInput is imported? If you console.log X within useEffect does it output?

Comment: If you can add your imports for InputPipelineDebugger, as well as the BeatsInput component, that would be helpful.

Comment: I've edited the thread with the requested code. useEffect and BeatsInput are imported and the console.log output correctly.

Comment: And I've tried useLayoutEffect too, but it's not working

Comment: Can you add EuiTabbedContent? That's the last hold out; I'm not seeing anything odd above.

Comment: EuiTabbedContent is a Kibana Gui component. I've tried everything, even call useLayoutEffect from the parent of the flyout, nothing seems to work. I just want to call a rest call and build my tabs according to the response and it's like the most difficult thing to do.

Comment: Ah ok, I am able to recreate the issue and will post an answer if i find it. I think it definitely relates to the EuiTabbedComponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change initialSelectedTab to selectedTab [or just add it in addition to]

https://elastic.github.io/eui/#/navigation/tabs

> You can also use the selectedTab and
> onTabClick props to take complete control over tab selection. This can
> be useful if you want to change tabs based on user interaction with
> another part of the UI.

Or work around:

1. give tabs an empty default value

```
 const [tabs, setTabs] = useState();
```

2. render the component conditionally around tabs

```
{tabs && (
        <EuiTabbedContent
          tabs={tabs}
          initialSelectedTab={tabs[0]}
          autoFocus="selected"
          onTabClick={tab => {
            onTabConnectionTypeClicked(tab);
          }}
        />
      )}
```

Comment: You save my day! For real! Really thank you Pavlos!